# Split txt file into multiple new files with regex using python

Tags: python, text

I have several files in .txt format, with novels inside.

Each files are pretty large (>20Mb) and I want to split them into smaller files.

But I found pattern in those files as follows:

```
________(Empty line or with several spaces)
________(Empty line or with several spaces)
Book I (or II, III, IV, V...): (book title)
________(Empty line or with several spaces)
Chapter 1 (2,3,4...): (chapter title)
________(Empty line or with several spaces)
(\t or two space)(main text)
```

I would like to know how can I split the files into different folders, each folders contains .txt files named like B1C20.txt (with text from Book one chapter 20) or B3C20-50.txt (with text from Book three chapter twenty to fifty)?

I've tried to use python readlines or re.findall to do the job and delete the empty space at the beginning of each lines but the script seems to stop, keep running without output anything. Is it because the files are too large? Or are there any online tools that can do the job? Thanks!!

Comment: please share your regex and [mcve]

Comment: "pretty large (>20Mb)" that's not large by today's standards, for what it's worth.  and you can read from the same file in multiple places so there's really no compelling reason to split them down.